# Database Runtime Exception while inserting a row in a column that doesn't appear in source code

Tags: android, sqlite, debugging

While running my app, logcat is showing an exception:

```
09-28 16:37:33.364     853-2228/? E/SQLiteDatabase? Error inserting
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column context_id is not unique (code 19)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
    at com.google.android.contextmanager.q.al.a(SourceFile:408)
    at com.google.android.contextmanager.q.al.b(SourceFile:383)
    at com.google.android.contextmanager.q.al.a(SourceFile:349)
    at com.google.android.contextmanager.q.al.b(SourceFile:376)
    at com.google.android.contextmanager.g.a.j.a(SourceFile:58)
    at com.google.android.contextmanager.g.a.a.run(SourceFile:52)
    at com.google.android.contextmanager.g.i.handleMessage(SourceFile:215)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

My problem is, context_id column doesn't appear when I do a full search in whole project. The exception info point to classes from android libs, not my code.

Any clues, how to track this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that has started appearing in android devices after one of the recent updates. It most likely has nothing to do with your app.

Unless you're doing communication with other apps/services and need to see what they're logging you should probably filter your logs on the first of the numbers in `1234-4321/ABCD` as that is the process-id of the process that produced the log-message. Find a message that you know to come from your app and use that as reference.

If you're using Android Studio it should also be possible to select your application from a dropdown-list, and select "Show only selected application", which will have the same effect as what I described above.